# Merge rows with linq in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

everyone, i have this json. This is a simplified one. It is stored in a var called **employee**

```
[
    {
        "ID": "AAVA",
        "PRENOM": "Test",
        "NOM": "Test",
        "HORAIRE": [
            25
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "AAVA",
        "PRENOM": "Test",
        "NOM": "Test",
        "HORAIRE": [
            23
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to merge the 2 row in one row merging the column "HORAIRE" giving something like this

```
[
    {
        "ID": "AAVA",
        "PRENOM": "Test",
        "NOM": "Test",
        "HORAIRE": [
            25, 23
        ]
    },

]
```

I am stuck at this line.

```
var result = employee.GroupBy(l => l.ID).Select(d => new EMPLOYEE_SUMMARY_DTO
            {
                ID = d.Key,
                //HORAIRE = d.Select(h => h.HORAIRE)
            });
```

Comment: Is your "HORAIRE" column on your first json string is really an array [] of strings? or just a string?

Comment: @ljpv14 I defined it as a list `public List<int> HORAIRE { get; set; }`

Comment: I clarified it since it's kind of confusing when you showed what you want to accomplish it as array of strings. There you go, you have some great answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroupBy` will return a sequence of `IGrouping` that is a sequence of the items in each group as well of the key identifying that group. I assume that all items with the same `ID` also have the same `PRENOM` and `NOM` so you can pick the first item in the grouping to get these two properties.

You also need to merge `HORAIRE` into a single list. Here I have made the assumption that the source `HORARIRE` values can contain multiple elements so `SelectMany` is used to flatten this list of lists. As you probably want to merge duplicates `Distinct` is used for that purpose.

```
var result = employee
    .GroupBy(l => l.ID)
    .Select(d => new EMPLOYEE_SUMMARY_DTO
        {
            ID = d.Key,
            PRENOM = d.First().PRENOM,
            NOM = d.First().NOM,
            HORAIRE = d.SelectMany(h => h.HORARIRE).Distinct().ToList()
        });
```

There is an overload to `GroupBy` where you can avoid the `Select`. However, to match the code that you have provided I'm not using that overload.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use selectMany and toArray methods like this:

```
HORAIRE = d.SelectMany(h => h.HORAIRE).ToArray();
```